# Graph Database Not updated Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j version 3.1.0 . i have created 20 million graph.Each graph consists of 9 nodes with their respective properties.I am using embedded mode (api 3.1.0) .I am trying to change the property of a node .In the runtime I changed property of a node but it is not reflecting in the database when i am trying to fetch the node property using neo4j shell.

The database size is almost 20GB.I am running it on a server. i Guess that  the changes are taking place in cache but it is not reflected in graph database.What changes should i make to get updated in the graph database???

```
try(Transaction tx=GraphCreation.getInstance().dbService.beginTx()){
            Node n= GraphCreation.getInstance().dbService.findNode(MyLabels.IMSI,"IMSI" ,"A"+0);
            n.setProperty("MSISDN", "Z"+0);


            tx.success(); // commit


        }   catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try(Transaction tx=GraphCreation.getInstance().dbService.beginTx())
        {
         String cql ="match(a:IMSI{IMSI : 'A0'}) return a.MSISDN";              
            Result result= GraphCreation.getInstance().dbService.execute(cql);
            while ( result.hasNext() )
             {
                 Map<String, Object> row = result.next();
                 for ( String key : result.columns() )
                 {
                     System.out.printf( "%s = %s%n", key, row.get( key ) );
                 }
             }
            tx.success(); 
            timerContext.close();

        }   catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I have used tx.success() also

Comment: Can you share the relevant code-snippet (in which you do the update) ? And when you say neo4j shell ... you mean you start up the embedded database in server mode and attach to it ? Are you sure (just checking) that you are connecting to the same database ?

Comment: I believe the 3.1.0 version also has embedded Cypher capabilities. Can you run a graphdb.execute(cypherquery) on the embedded database in a second transaction to verify your change went through ?

Comment: Yeah , I am using the same database .After the updation of a particular node . I am fetching that node property from the Graph DB still im getting the previous value. But when i find the node from db and fetch the property in the run time at the time of updation im getting the updated value. So i guess it is reflected in cache not in graph DB.

Comment: Just for my understanding ... you're not running embedded transactions on the database at the same (!) time that you have it started in server mode ... right ?

Comment: Yes. I am not running at same time.I am running it in Linux.

Comment: Ok. Can you try the embedded Cypher-query in a second (!) transaction (in the same code) and see if that shows the changed property ? Because if it does it should be persisted. And can you share the code ?

Comment: Ok i will try and let u know. thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: Using cypher i have got the updated value. But how because when i connect to a shell i am getting previous value.can u tell me the reason. But for 1 million graph  i am getting updated value from the shell also.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the database is not correctly closed (in the embedded mode) before you open it in server mode (or vice versa ... it is not yet closed in server mode before you open it in embedded mode). Can you share the actual code ?

Comment: I have shared the code.It says in the first transaction im updating a node property  and in the second transaction im fetching the property of that node.

Comment: That looks fine. Now, are you sure you're passing through a shutdown() in embedded mode before you are starting things in server mode ?

Comment: No. Im not doing that.But everything is going well for 1 million graph(updated data is fetched using shell) but not for 20 million graph.what is the difference .can u tell me? and also where should i call shutdown method.

Comment: Thanks a lot,sir . The problem has been solved!!!!! i have added code  for shutdown .then works perfectly..Now the DB has shutdown properly .. :) thank u so much....

Comment: The problem was of course that while the embedded database is consistent, not everything is consistent on disk yet. Only a shutdown() does that :-)

Comment: Yeah .Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved .Graph DB hasn't been shutdown properly when trying to stop the code by pressing Cntrl +C.Hence to handle this case  add this snippet to your code.

```
private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
{
    // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
    // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
    // running application).
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    } );
}
```